# ServerSocket scope in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, sockets

Does `Spring` provide some kind of server socket scope?

I'm working with a legacy library that opens a socket and calls my application by reflection. Which means, I cannot use spring directly here (I know it's possible with aspects).

I'm thinking of extracting the needed code parts and itegrate them into my spring application. Which is similar to the following: 
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);

```
do {
    Socket client = socket.accept(); //wait for connection
    ThreadExecutor.delegate(client); //delegate execution to another thread
} while(true);
```

Therefore, I wonder:

- what the Spring pendant to `java.net.ServerSocket` is?
- if Spring can provide a scope that is tied to a single socket connection? Similar to a http session scope, but just for the lifetime of the a single active socket connection? So that I could use dependency injection throughout my application. And also could use "session/state" aware services that are automatically cleared when socket is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like thread scope might help you.  It wont be tied to the socket, but to the thread handling the socket socket (but you normally have one thread per socket connection).  Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch03s05.html).